# How to restrict an app's login with a database?

Tags: java, spring, database

I am carrying out a web application project made with Spring in which I use HTML, Java and Oracle SQL (for the database). My question is that one of my HTML codes is for a login in the app, but I would like to be able to link it with the database, so that access to the web is only allowed if the user and password entered are in the USER table of the database.  This is my actual HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iniciosesion</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <img src="Imagenes%20de%20inicio/icono.png">
        <h2>Usuario</h2>
        <input type ="text" name = "username">
        <h2>Contraseña</h2>
        <input type ="text" name = "password">
        <a href="index.html"><input type="button" value="Ir"></a>
        <form action="Coger_datos" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Ir">
        </form>

        <a href="usuario/add.html"><input type="button" value="Crear cuenta"></a>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also found a Java template to access an Oracle database, but I don't know how to relate it to my HTML code so that everything connects:

```
package es.uma.ingsoftware.goldendumbbell.Controller;

import java.sql.*;


public class Coger_datos {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("\nEstableciendo conexión...");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("zzzzz", "xxxxxx", "yyyyy");
        System.out.println("Conexión establecida\n");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String consulta = "SELECT CONTRASEÑA FROM USUARIO where usuario.nombre = 'javimp2003'";
        System.out.println("Se va a ejecutar la consulta: " + consulta);
        System.out.println("\nIniciando transacción...");
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);

        System.out.println("Resultado de la consulta:");
        while (rset.next()) { 
            int ncol = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= ncol; i++) { // for: Itera sobre las columnas de la fila
                System.out.print(rset.getString(i));
                if (i < ncol)
                    System.out.print(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Finalizando transacción...");
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("\nConexión finalizada");
    }
}
```

This is the preview of the login:

[image]

....................

Comment: You need to do simple authentication. Please check this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ after you will need to add connection with DB to verify user.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you need to know how to link the login page with the data base. This should be common knowledge that you should connect the database tables with the Spring app and from the front-end send http requests to the spring app. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube on how to do that and i think Amigoscode explains it best.
To limit the access with a login page you need to create a form on your page, retrieve the data from the form, then call the method from the Spring app that gives you the person by name or by email depending on what you ask in the form then compare the password from the form with the password from the user retrieved from the database.
There should also be noted that you need to use a framework like react to code all the front end because the html will not be enough.
This is a snipped on how I implemented the request.

```
const response = await fetch(
      //the port should be 8080 if you use spring `http://localhost:8080/pathToControllerClass/IdentifierToDifferentiateMethods/${parameterFromTheForm}`
    );
// and this is how you should handle the verification
const data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok && name === data.name && pass === data.password) {
      authContext.login();
      handleLogin(data.id);
      props.onFormSwitch("home");
    }
```